# allow usb debugging rsa key fingerprint not coming in windows

Tags: android, usb-debugging

usb debugging rsa key fingerprint is not asking in my home computer. but when i run at my office computer it runs fine.
Please help me in fixing the problem.

Comment: wat code. it is not related to code. when i connect mobile to check for debugging it it not asking rsa key fingerprint

Comment: in **Develoepr Options**, tap **Revoke USB debugging authorizations**, then try plug your device again to your computer